# How can I add programatically service dependencies to an installed Window service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi, wmi-query

How can I add programatically   service dependencies to an installed Window service ?

It would really helpful, If someone suggest solution using WMI through the `System.Management` namespace . What is property for dependencies on which I can set services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [Change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method of the [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28VS.85%29.aspx) class. The last parameter is a doubly-NULL-terminated list of dependencies.